# Waiting for component doesn't work when the message is hidden (Slash command)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to build a card game at discord. Actually, i don't know how to call this game in English. This game has private information which can be seen by only one person, that's why I use hidden message (await ctx.send(content, hidden = True)). I also use components for users can react to these messages, but it doesn't work. Basically, the button components appear, it looks correctly. I used wait_for_component, but when I click on the button, the wait_for_component returns a None and fails.
When I remove the parameter "hidden = True", everything works well. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
lis = [create_button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label=f"{card}") for card in
               self._player_cards[ctx.guild.id][ctx.author]]
action_row = spread_to_rows(*lis)
await ctx.send(embed=embed,
               components=action_row,
               hidden = True
              )
while True:
        button_ctx: ComponentContext = await wait_for_component(self.client, components=action_row)
        print(button_ctx.component)
```